# I have question with this left-rotate algorithm for red and black trees

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I'm almost done with this assignment, but I'm having trouble applying this algorithm into my code for an assignment. I'm just confused with what is T and what it does in the code from the picture.

[image: The code from the picture is a left-rotate algorithm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` is the tree in which the rotate operation is being performed. Note the references in the algorithm to `T.root`.